# "eglConfig not initialized" error, but I'm not using openGl

Tags: android, android-widget

This is very weird, since I don't use any opengl in my app!

I get this stack trace (thanks to ACRA):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: eglConfig not initialized
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initializeEgl(HardwareRenderer.java:582)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initialize(HardwareRenderer.java:518)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1300)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Some clues:

- It started to happen only in a version of my app that I've added a Widget. So it is likely related to Widget rendering
- I happened several times, and it appears to originate from the same device
- This device reports different screen size every time...

Something all the reports have in common:

- PHONE_MODEL = cm_tenderloin
- BRAND = generic
- PRODUCT   = touchpad
- ANDROID_VERSION = 4.0.4
- same "INSTALLATION_ID"
- same "SERIAL", which is unnaturally long

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: On ICS hardware acceleration is on by default. And even with previous versions window compositing was done with hw acceleration. Is this happening performing a specific operation?

Comment: This is a countdown timer, and while it's running and the screen is on - I update the widget's simple TextField every second. The TextField does have a style with a shade.

Comment: If it was related to hw acceleration, I'd expect more devices to have this problem. At least for now, it's only this (apparently) one device, but multiple times

Comment: According to the stack, it seems related to hardware acceleration. It might be good to ask to the manufacturer I guess. Anyway, you can try to check if those views are actually hw accelerated or also try to turn it off for the entire activity or even the entire application using android:hardwareAccelerated tag in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I cannot replicate it, since it's reported from an anonymous user(s). But I can send this to whoever made the mod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking up "cm_tenderloin" in google, I see that it's a cyanogen mod for hp's tenderloin.

Maybe they implemented an home replacement that does its rendering stack with openGl. I wonder if my widget is the only one suffering.

I still have no idea how each report have a different screen size for the same device. What is the chance my unknown Widget is used by the very developer of this home replacement, and he is emulating various screen sizes? (close to zero)

edit -

I've found a [post](http://rootzwiki.com/topic/30756-eglconfig-not-initialized/) that suggests that this problem doesn't relate to my code, but rather to a faulty installation of drivers in rooted/modded device.